# How to reference other frameworks from my binding?

Tags: c#, ios, binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind a library that depends on multiple frameworks. Here's the documentation on how to set it up on xcode: http://sdk.camera360.com/page/iosguide.

In essence it depends on the following external frameworks:

```
pg_edit_sdk_common.framework 
pg_edit_sdk_cdb_piratesdk.framework
```

The following iOS Frameworks:

```
CoreMotion.framework
AVFoundation.framework
CoreMedia.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreImage.framework
ImageIO.framework
libstdc++.6.dylib
libz.1.2.5.dylib
```

and it sounds like it also needs the flags:

```
-std=c++11 and -all_load
```

I am binding `PhotoEditFrameWork.a` utilizing `Sharpie` and a Binding Project. The `PhotoEditFramework.linkwith.cs` looks like this:

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("PhotoEditFramework.a", SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true, 
    Frameworks="CoreMotion AVFoundation CoreMedia CoreData CoreGraphics CoreImage ImageIO", 
    LinkerFlags = "-all_load -lstdc++.6 -lz.1.2.5 -std=c++11")]
```

But when I try to run the app I get the following errors:

```
    MTOUCH: error MT5209: Native linking error: warning: ignoring file /Code/Tests/Camera360/Camera360Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/PhotoEditFramework.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Code/Tests/Camera360/Camera360Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/PhotoEditFramework.a (2 slices)
    MTOUCH: error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _PhotoEditFrameworkVersionString. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Camera360.Constants.PhotoEditFrameworkVersionString. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
    MTOUCH: error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _PhotoEditFrameworkVersionNumber. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Camera360.Constants.PhotoEditFrameworkVersionNumber. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked.
```

The first error is related to the simulator. Is that because the library is missing the i386 target?
I think the other two errors are related to references to `pg_edit_sdk_common.framework` and `pg_edit_sdk_cdb_piratesdk.framework`. How do I reference those two frameworks on `LinkWith`. Furthermore, do I need to bind those as well?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in your first assumption. The native library is likely missing a target for i386. You can confirm by following the directions [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/#Missing_Required_Architecture_i386).

To fix the issue with the external frameworks, you can add as many required native libraries into the binding project as needed. In this case, grab the native .a file from both the required pg_*.framework files and add them into the binding project.

Note* After you add the .a libraries, you'll get more LinkWith.cs files for those libraries. Make sure the `LinkTarget` is set. I noticed your existing one does not have it either. Update that. It should be something like this:

`LinkTarget = LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator`

However, you'll need to make sure the `LinkTarget`s match whatever the .a supports. Use the technique in the first link to check that (`lipo -info`)

There are also some other workarounds noted [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT5214_Native_linking_failed_undefined_symbol_._This_symbol_was_referenced_the_managed_member_._Please_verify_that_all_the_necessary_frameworks_have_been_referenced_and_native_libraries_linked.) if the above does not apply.

Comment: Was just part of some edited text, see the revisions http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36269451/revisions

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. I missed a few characters when editing out some incorrect information. Thanks chrisntr for catching it.